# ¿Por qué no se está aplicando la fuente de letra usando CSS?

Tags: html, css

¿Por qué no se está aplicando la fuente de letra Monserrat en el botón? Creo que es correcto todo lo insertado, a pesar de que lo he revisado varias veces. ¿Alguna solución? Gracias de antemano.

```css
.myButton {
    background-color:#ffffff;
    border:1px solid #000000;
    display:inline-block;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:#000000;
    font-family:'Montserrat';
    font-size:16px;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:16px 18px;
    text-decoration:none;
    transition:background-color 0.5s, color 0.5s;
    
}
.myButton:hover {
    background-color:#000000;
    color:#ffffff;
}
.myButton:active {
    position:relative;
    top:1px;
}
```

```html
<head>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat' rel='stylesheet'>
</head>
<a href="#" class="myButton">Texto del botón</a>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En el CSS colocaste:

```css
    font-family:'Monserrat';
```

**Monserrat**

Y según el enlace que la incluye:

```html
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat' rel='stylesheet'>
```

La fuente se llama:

**Montserrat**

Nótese esa T ---- Mon**t**serrat

Comment: No lo sabia y no entiendo el motivo, pero si dices, tomo nota para la próxima

Comment: ¿Qué significa OP?

Comment: @Programandosiempre Es un término común a todos los sitios en Stack Exchange, que se usa para hacer referencia a la persona que hizo la pregunta. _Original Poster_, que en una traducción algo ligera sería _Quien inició el hilo_. [fuente](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253162/what-is-an-op-when-referring-to-stack-exchange)

Comment: Gracias por el dato @Alfabravo, yo también me preguntaba que era OP, lo infería pero no estaba seguro

Answer (score 1):

Lo tienes mal escrito es de la siguiente manera;

font-family:'Montserrat';

Comment: De acuerdo. Muchas gracias.